# AssertMacros: queueEntry error -ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

What does this error mean?

```
AssertMacros: queueEntry,  file: /SourceCache/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-920.1.11/hid.subproj/IOHIDEventQueue.c, line: 512
AssertMacros: queueEntry,  file: /SourceCache/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-920.1.11/hid.subproj/IOHIDEventQueue.c, line: 512
AssertMacros: queueEntry,  file: /SourceCache/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-920.1.11/hid.subproj/IOHIDEventQueue.c, line: 512
AssertMacros: queueEntry,  file: /SourceCache/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-920.1.11/hid.subproj/IOHIDEventQueue.c, line: 512
```

I am getting this error when starting the application

Comment: What language? What SDK? What code?????

Comment: I think this is a quirk of the current iOS 7 beta, but without more information about what you're doing it is hard to say.  The beta is under NDA, so I can't discuss it here, but there is [a related post on the Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/197966?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Finally gone in the GM release!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is isolated to iOS 7 Beta. Since the beta is under NDA, you will need to visit the Apple Developer forums for more information.

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/197966?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: So I think that we can't upgrade our apps to iOS7 for now, until they fix that crucial problem :/.

Answer (score 27):

Change your main.m file like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"


typedef int (*PYStdWriter)(void *, const char *, int);
static PYStdWriter _oldStdWrite;

int __pyStderrWrite(void *inFD, const char *buffer, int size)
{
    if ( strncmp(buffer, "AssertMacros:", 13) == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return _oldStdWrite(inFD, buffer, size);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    _oldStdWrite = stderr->_write;
    stderr->_write = __pyStderrWrite;
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is going on here, it worked for me, -he says with eyebrows skeptically furrowed

Comment: Looks like it's not solving the error, just causing it to not display.