# AssertMacros ios7 appearing in debugger

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I am seeing the following warning in Xcode5 when scrolling on a UITableView...

```
AssertMacros: queueEntry,  file: /SourceCache/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-920.1.11/hid.subproj/IOHIDEventQueue.c, line: 512
```

Any ideas on why I am getting this?

Comment: Apple forgot to turn off a debug message, nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178237/assertmacros-queueentry-error-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK to the latest version (public release) instead of the beta, and this will fix itself.